# Android Studio - org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-studio

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in my code?

I have this format in my PHP:

```
....//Some query from mysql table
foreach($data as $row) {
   $response["error"] = FALSE;
   $response["notification"]["_id"] = $row["id"];                   
   echo json_encode($response);
}
```

In my Java, I have this:

```
try {
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
   JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("notification");
   JSONObject json_data = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
      json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
      String iid = json_data.getString("_id");
      .... //Use the requested id here
   }
} catch(Exception e) {
   Log.e("EE", String.valueOf(e));
}
```

I didn't get the expected result.  In my log, it says:

```
EE: org.json.JSONException: Value {"_id":1} at notification of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I have no idea on what is wrong since I'm just a newbie.  Could anyone help me please???

Comment: post your json response

Comment: "JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray"... simple.

Comment: Your exception tells it all to you: `Value {"_id":1}` is not an array.

Comment: any example on how can i achieve what i want? i am very new in android. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here what i did to fixed my problem:

**PHP**

```
....//Some query from mysql table
$posts = array(); //Added
foreach($data as $row) {
    $posts[] = array('post'=>$row); //New 
}echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts)); //then print here
```

**ANDROID JAVA**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");

for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

   JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String s = e.getString("post");
  JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);

   String iid = jObject.getString("id"); //Put the id here or you can add more if you have more than 1 column
   Log.w("THE REQUESTED ID ARE",iid);
    .... //Use the requested id here
}
```

Thanks for this link:

[Send and Receive JSON between Android and PHP Web Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php)

Thanks.